# Prevent Y scrollbar on parent and adding scrollbar to child

Tags: html, css

I have a parent that is used as a React component and has a scrollbar, I cannot change the parent but in a certain case I'd like the parent not to display the scrollbar and instead have the child scroll while taking up all the vertical space that is available.

```html
<div id="parent" style="overflow: auto;">
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <div id="child" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 600px;">
    <div style="height: 1200px; background-color: green;"></div>
  </div>
</div>;
```

I can prevent the div with id `parent` to show a scrollbar but only know how to by setting div with id `child` to have a fixed height, how could this be accomplished with `child` taking up the rest of the height of the page?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

The `flex-grow` property specifies how much the item will grow relative to the rest of the flexible items inside the same container.

```html
<div id="parent" style="overflow: hidden; display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 300px;">
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <div id="child" style="overflow-y: scroll; flex-grow: 1;">
    <div style="height: 1200px; background-color: green;"></div>
  </div>
</div>;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I can't apply this: `I have a parent that is used as a React component and has a scrollbar, I cannot change the parent` The parent has many routes and in all of those routes it needs to look the way it looks. I'll try and see if I can get access to the parent and give it a header and footer prop but it would be unlikely that would happen.